# What unit of measurement does Blender OBJ export?

Tags: modeling, export, import

I'm trying to export my model from the Blender Imperial Unit setup into Rhino 3D Imperial Unit file. There is no option in Blender export to determine the scale. I know I can manually scale the model up in Rhino but I'm likely going to need to import and export back and forth and it would be great if I didn't need to worry about scaling each time.

Comment: After some trial and error, I discovered it''s meters.